# DLL errors while running gstreamer C pipeline that is compiled to EXE

Tags: dll, linker, mingw, gstreamer, linker-errors

I have a gstreamer pipeline in C I have compiled it using MinGW and got the EXE file.
but when I am trying to run the exe I got huge list of dll errors.
I have confirmed that these dll files are present in the respective dir.
I have compiled the same c pipeline in linux it works fine on linux.

these are the error logs when I try to run the genrated exe file

````
(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libges-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libges-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgio-2.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgio-2.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgobject-2.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstcodecs-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstcodecs-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstgl-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstgl-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstpbutils-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstpbutils-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstplayer-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstplayer-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstrtsp-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstrtsp-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstrtspserver-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstrtspserver-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgsttranscoder-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgsttranscoder-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstvalidate-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstvalidate-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstvideo-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libgstvideo-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libharfbuzz-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libharfbuzz-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libjson-glib-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libjson-glib-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpango-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpango-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpangocairo-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpangoft2-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libpangowin32-1.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libsoup-2.4-1.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\bin\libsoup-2.4-1.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaiff.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaiff.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstalpha.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstalpha.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstalphacolor.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstalphacolor.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstapetag.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstapetag.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstasf.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstasf.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstassrender.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstassrender.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaudioparsers.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaudioparsers.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaudiovisualizers.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstaudiovisualizers.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.     

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstavi.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstavi.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstbayer.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstbayer.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdeinterlace.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdeinterlace.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdv.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdv.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdvbsuboverlay.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdvbsuboverlay.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdvdspu.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdvdspu.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdvdsub.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstdvdsub.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsteffectv.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsteffectv.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstencoding.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstencoding.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstfieldanalysis.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstfieldanalysis.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstflv.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstflv.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstfrei0r.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstfrei0r.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgaudieffects.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgaudieffects.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgdkpixbuf.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgdkpixbuf.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgeometrictransform.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgeometrictransform.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. 

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstges.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstges.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgoom.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgoom.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgoom2k1.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstgoom2k1.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsthls.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsthls.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstid3demux.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstid3demux.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstinter.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstinter.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstinterlace.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstinterlace.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstisomp4.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstisomp4.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstivtc.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstivtc.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstjpeg.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstjpeg.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstlegacyrawparse.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstlegacyrawparse.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstlibav.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstlibav.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstlibvisual.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstlibvisual.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmatroska.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmatroska.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmpegpsdemux.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmpegpsdemux.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmpegtsdemux.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmpegtsdemux.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmpegtsmux.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmpegtsmux.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmultifile.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmultifile.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmxf.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstmxf.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstnvcodec.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstnvcodec.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstogg.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstogg.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopengl.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopengl.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenh264.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenjpeg.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopenjpeg.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopus.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopus.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopusparse.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstopusparse.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstoverlaycomposition.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstoverlaycomposition.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. 

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstpango.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstpango.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstplayback.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstplayback.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstpng.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstpng.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstpnm.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstpnm.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrawparse.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrawparse.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrealmedia.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrealmedia.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstreplaygain.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstreplaygain.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstresindvd.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstresindvd.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrfbsrc.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrfbsrc.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrsvg.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrsvg.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtp.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtp.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtpmanager.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtpmanager.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtsp.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtsp.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtspclientsink.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstrtspclientsink.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstshapewipe.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstshapewipe.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsmooth.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsmooth.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsmpte.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsmpte.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoup.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstsoup.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttheora.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttheora.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttimecode.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttimecode.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttypefindfunctions.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsttypefindfunctions.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.   

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideobox.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideobox.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideoconvert.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideoconvert.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideocrop.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideocrop.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideofilter.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideofilter.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideofiltersbad.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideofiltersbad.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.       

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideomixer.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideomixer.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideoparsersbad.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideoparsersbad.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.       

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideorate.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideorate.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideoscale.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideoscale.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideotestsrc.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvideotestsrc.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvoaacenc.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvoaacenc.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvpx.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstvpx.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwavparse.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwavparse.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwinscreencap.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstwinscreencap.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstx264.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstx264.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsty4mdec.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsty4mdec.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsty4menc.dll': 
'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgsty4menc.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstzbar.dll': 'D:\gstreamer\1.0\mingw_x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0\libgstzbar.dll': The specified procedure could not be found.
  0 C:\Users\USAMA WIZARD\Desktop\Build\electron-mediasoup-gst\src\lib\sendrecrtp.exe 

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_is_valid_property: object class 'GstPipeline' has no property named 'buffer-mode'

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_add_many: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element_1)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_link_many: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element_1)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_link_many: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element_1)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(sendrecrtp.exe:11696): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pasted the generated exe file to bin directory of gstreamer and it worked
fine.